# SQL Server - Calculate Initial Bearing from Latitude & Longitude using GEOGRAPHY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Recently, from the help of Stackoverflow members, I got the following solution to calculate distance between two latitude and longitude points:

```
GEOGRAPHY::Point(DepartureAirportLatitude, DepartureAirportLongitude, 4326)
        .STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(ArrivalAirportLatitude, ArrivalAirportLongitude, 4326)) AS [Default],

        GEOGRAPHY::Point(DepartureAirportLatitude, DepartureAirportLongitude, 4326)
        .STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(ArrivalAirportLatitude, ArrivalAirportLongitude, 4326)) / 1609.344 AS [Mi],

        GEOGRAPHY::Point(DepartureAirportLatitude, DepartureAirportLongitude, 4326)
        .STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(ArrivalAirportLatitude, ArrivalAirportLongitude, 4326)) / 1000 AS [Km]
```

Is there a way, using the GEOGRAPHY feature, to calculate the initial bearing between the same data points, displaying it as a heading?

Thanks

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply and the information.

After a few hours of playing around and extensive amounts of Google searching, I am using the below solution which is giving me the correct results:

```
DECLARE @Pi AS FLOAT
DECLARE @D2R AS FLOAT

SET @Pi = '3.14159265358979'
SET @D2R = @Pi / 180.0;


PICalculation AS
(
    SELECT FlightNo, DepartureAirportIATA, ArrivalAirportIATA,

        @D2R * DepartureAirportLatitude AS [DepartureAirportLatitude], @D2R * DepartureAirportLongitude AS [DepartureAirportLongitude],
        @D2R * ArrivalAirportLatitude AS [ArrivalAirportLatitude], @D2R * ArrivalAirportLongitude AS [ArrivalAirportLongitude]

    FROM RawData    
),

RadiansCalculation AS
(
    SELECT FlightNo, DepartureAirportIATA, ArrivalAirportIATA,

            Radians(ArrivalAirportLatitude - DepartureAirportLatitude) AS [DLat],
            Radians(ArrivalAirportLongitude - DepartureAirportLongitude) AS [DLon],
            Radians(DepartureAirportLatitude) AS [RLat1],
            Radians(ArrivalAirportLatitude) AS [RLat2]

    FROM PICalculation  
),

XYCalculation AS
(
    SELECT FlightNo, DepartureAirportIATA, ArrivalAirportIATA,

        SIN(DLon)*COS(RLat2) AS [Y],
        COS(RLat1)*SIN(RLat2)-SIN(RLat1)*COS(RLat2)*COS(DLon) AS [X]

    FROM RadiansCalculation
),

HeadingCalculation AS
(
    SELECT FlightNo, DepartureAirportIATA, ArrivalAirportIATA,

        CASE WHEN X = 0 AND Y = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE CAST((DEGREES(ATN2(Y,X)) + 360) AS DECIMAL(5,1)) % 360 
        END AS [InitialBearing]

    FROM XYCalculation
)

SELECT *
FROM DataJoin
```

Hopefully this solution will be useful to others who stumble across this post as well :)

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scalar function and test points that exercise it. NB: I found the source [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4630ef22-2525-486c-8904-68b47d1c02a3/calculating-bearings-between-2-geoographic-points?forum=sqlspatial)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Bearing (
  @point1 geography,
  @point2 geography  )
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Bearing decimal(18,15)
  DECLARE @Lat1 float = Radians(@point1.Lat)
  DECLARE @Lat2 float = Radians(@point2.Lat)
  DECLARE @dLon float = Radians(@point2.Long - @point1.Long)
  IF (@point1.STEquals(@point2) = 1)
    SET @Bearing = NULL
  ELSE
    SET @Bearing = ATN2(
      sin(@dLon)*cos(@Lat2),
     (cos(@Lat1)*sin(@Lat2)) - (sin(@Lat1)*cos(@Lat2)*cos(@dLon))
    )
    SET @Bearing = (Degrees(@Bearing) + 360) % 360
  RETURN @Bearing
END
GO

DECLARE @g  GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(43, 43, 4326);
DECLARE @g1 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(42, 43, 4326);
DECLARE @g2 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(44, 43, 4326);
DECLARE @g3 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(43, 42, 4326);
DECLARE @g4 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(43, 44, 4326);

SELECT dbo.[Bearing](@g, @g1),
    [dbo].[Bearing](@g, @g2),
    [dbo].[Bearing](@g, @g3),
    [dbo].[Bearing](@g, @g4);
```

If doing this in T-SQL ends up being too slow, there are a couple of CLR implementations at that link as well.